# HTML - Constant placeholder at the end of the text?

Tags: html

Is it possible to have a placeholder at the end of the text field, that is always present and always goes to the end of the input?

I want to have something an input that says '(click to edit)'. Once yu click and edit it, I still want it to say '(click to edit)' at the end of your text, so that it is reminder that this is still editable.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a label? If your user inputs some large text how would they see the "click to edit" since its going to be appended to the end of the text value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :after pseudo selector:

html:

```
<div class="input_wrapper">
    <input/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.input_wrapper:after {
    content:"click to edit";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I'll vote it as soon as I can

Answer (score 2):

there is a `bootstrap` [implementation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Click to edit</span>
</div>
```

or you can make it(if you need to have it as a value of the input) with javascript: add and remove from the `value` property before and after edit